# Styling props not working, especially padding

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I am still new to react-native and I have some troubles regarding the styling props of react-native.

I created a screen in my app and all my relevant code is this:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator, Alert, ImageBackground} from 'react-native'; 
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';

const NewLetterScreen = props =>{
    return(
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <ImageBackground source={require('../components/pictures/welcome.png')} style={{width:"100%", height:"100%", alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                <ImageBackground source={require('../components/pictures/letters/paper1.jpg')} style={styles.paper}>

                </ImageBackground>
            </ImageBackground>
        </View>
    )
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    paper:{
        width: "90%",
        height: "90%"
    }
});

export default NewLetterScreen;
```

The problem I face now is, that the "paper" I want to display is not centered, even tho I stricly declare this in the wrapping ImageBackground with justifyContent and alignItems. It is displaced to far up and to far on the left side and looks like this:

[image]

Also, if I try to use padding to get this stuff centered somehow, it doesnt work. I want to do padding from left and right, so horizontaly, but if I apply "paddingHorizontal: 50" to my styles.paper, the result is the following:

[image]

As you see, the "paddingHorizontal:50" works like a paddingLeft and that is definitely not what I intend.

I would be happy about any help regarding my styling props. Thanks in advance!

Comment: try adding justify-content: center; in the <view> style

Comment: `<parent style={{width:"100%", height:"100%",display:flex, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}><child></child></parent>`

Comment: Im sorry guys but both ideas didnt work, tried to apply the first suggestion and also the secound suggestion after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not add a margin of 10%? I always have problems with paddings. Try to avoid them.
Edit: Maybe it would help to just add a margin, instead of changing the width to 90%?

```js
import React from "react";
import { ImageBackground, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

const image = { uri: "https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png" };

const App = () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <ImageBackground source={image} style={styles.image}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Inside</Text>
    </ImageBackground>
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  image: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: "cover",
    justifyContent: "center",
    margin: "10%"  
  },
  text: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 42,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#000000a0"
  }
});

export default App;
```

You can copy&paste this example on https://reactnative.dev/docs/imagebackground

Comment: I rearranged my code and used margin, now it is displayed as I intended, thank you for the reminder with the "margin". Do you have any idea why margin is so much better then padding actualy?

Comment: I am glad that I could help you solve your issue. I think this has a lot to do with the box Model of the components. A margin is calculated differently than padding. As far as I know, padding is subtracted from the overall Space, whereas a Margin adds extra space. But as this is a very complex topic, I try to follow best practices and experience.

Comment: Will remember that for sure and from now on stick to lovely margin.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a wrapper for the inside image. You don't need margins or paddings.

```
const image1 = { uri: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597768130867-4c06bf86a2f3?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" };
const image2 = { uri: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611085857146-7b13f8b0a74f?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=641&q=80" };

const App = () => (
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <ImageBackground source={image1} style={styles.background}>
      <View style={styles.wrapper}>
        <ImageBackground source={image2}
          resizeMode="cover"
          style={styles.paper}>
        </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    </ImageBackground>
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  background: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  wrapper: {
    width: "90%",
    height: "90%",
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  paper: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%"
  }
});
```